# How to perform a MITM between a server and a client program whose local ports are randomly spawned?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, proxy

I usually used Burp or similar tools for browser-based communications. The client program in question doesn't offer a proxy option to be configured. So I can't use Burp in this case, besides ports are randomized. I can't edit host file to redirect traffic to localhost either as it doesn't resolve hostname to IP, it uses IP instead.

I need a windows-based tool as the client only runs on W7. Any idea?

Comment: Run in VM, route all traffic through proxy?

Comment: But I don't see a point in doing so. After all, the client program is communicating with the real server on the web and VM means bridging with the host OS. Can you give me more detail of your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: You can also configure a proxy server on operating system level if you have a second machine which you can configure as a proxy server. When you are sure that the communication protocol is HTTP then you could have a look at MITMproxy. Without a second machine you are left with a virtual machine with the host system configured as proxy server.

Comment: You could run a VM and configure it as a level 3 gateway. Set your app's OS to use the VM's IP as its default gateway. Therefore, all traffic will pass through the VM on the way to the destination IP. Burp has the option of setting an [invisible proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options_invisible.html). The tricky bit though is if random destination ports are used. Maybe you could PAT them to the same Burp listener?

Comment: @SilverlightFox I never thought the VM could be used that way. I will try that. Thanks!